# Sharing crashes in all apps

Tags: crashes, 8.0-oreo, share-menu

The sharing function in all apps crash on my phone. No matter what app I use, as long as I click on the share button, the app crashes and restarts before showing the list of apps I can share with.

My phone is a Huawei Honor 9 and the OS version is 8.0. I am an Android developer so I tried to get the exception from Android Studio:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
Process: com.google.android.apps.photos, PID: 19271
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at pu.done(PG:5)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.applicationInfo' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1960)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1900)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.queryIntentActivities(IPackageManager.java:3621)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:937)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationPackageManager.java:926)
    at aham.d(PG:7)
    at pi.d(PG:3)
    at pi.b(PG:19)
    at px.call(PG:5)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

It seems that this NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.applicationInfo' on a null object reference
```

is the cause to this problem.

I believe it's not the app's problem (in this case Google Photos) because it occurs in every app. So is it a system problem or is it caused by some other app I have installed? How can I find and uninstall that app if it's the latter case?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same in my Pixel 3, did you find how to solve it?

Comment: I backed up all my data, reinstalled the system, and restored the data. After that the problem is gone.